# Bandwidth flucation in Nvlink connection (p2pBandwidthLatencyTest)

Tags: gpu, topology

The topology of my cluster is demonstrated in the first pic: 
[image]

However, running the `p2pBandwidthLatencyTest`, I got an unpredicted result. The bandwidth between `2` and `3` is obviously lower than `0` and `1`. Is there anyone who knows the possible reason?

[image]

Comment: what sort of system is this?  Is it a Dell C4130 or C4140?

Comment: It is NF5288M5 from Inspur.

Answer (score -1):

Per to the technical support, it is due to the concrete hardware placement difference.